# Proof by induction of Complex Numbers $(Z^n)^*=(Z^*)^n$

Tags: complex-numbers, induction

Hi I have asked a few questions here before and people have been really helpful, just wondering if someone could help me out with this proof by induction question.

Simply: $(Z^n)^*=(Z^*)^n$ for all positive integers $n$.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=x+yi$.

For $n=2$:
$$
(z^*)^2 = (x - yi)^2=x^2-y^2-2xyi = (z^2)^*.
$$
Assume that it holds for $k=n-2$, i.e., 
$$
(z^*)^{n-2} = (z^{n-2})^*.
$$
Thus, for $(z^*)^n$
$$
(z^*)^n = (z^*)^{n-2}(z^*)^2=(z^{n-2})^*(z^2)^*=(z^{n-2}z^2)^*=(z^n)^*.
$$